# No fread function?

Tags: r, installation, data.table, fread

I keep trying to use `fread` as a function and R Studio returns to me

> could not find function "fread"

If I try to look for fread documentation by using `?fread` I get

> No documentation for ‘fread’ in specified packages and libraries:
>   you could try ‘??fread’

I have no idea why this could be the case. I was using this function very recently. I am running Ubuntu 18. Is there anyway I can repair my R installation or should I uninstall it? If uninstall, how do I go about doing so? Thank you.

Comment: try installing `data.table` package

Comment: @Bulat Thanks friend, I went ahead and pre-emptively deleted all of the R directories to reinstall the whole thing.

Comment: `fread` is not part of base R or Rstudio

Comment: Well glad I know that now. Thank you.

Comment: There's an `fread` in `data.table` or  in tidyverse/readr packages. You can search for package and function names at https://www.rdocumentation.org/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should install `data.table` package. Please see the code below:

```
install.packages("data.table")
library(data.table)

# functionality check
write.csv(data.frame(1), "test.csv")
dt <- fread("test.csv")
dt
#    V1 X1
# 1:  1  1
```